# How can I set the focus at an entry but at a button at the same time using tkinter python3?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, focus

I want to create a window that lets me start writing right away, but just after finishing, without having to press "tab" or anything else, just to press "Enter" to activate a button. Here an example code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Aplicacion():
    def __init__(self):
        self.raiz = Tk()
        self.raiz.title("Acces")

        self.etiq1 = ttk.Label(self.raiz, text="User:").pack()

        self.ctext1 = ttk.Entry(self.raiz, width=30)
        self.ctext1.pack()
        self.ctext1.focus_set()

#Thanks to the written so far I'm able to start writing 
#in the entry box right away, just after I start the program, 
#but if I press enter the next button is not activated.

        self.boton1 = ttk.Button(self.raiz, text="Accept", command=self.raiz.destroy)

        self.boton1.pack()

        self.raiz.mainloop()

def main():
    mi_app = Aplicacion()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set the focus at an entry but at a button at the same time using tkinter python3?

You cannot. Focus by definition can only refer to a single widget.

> I want to create a window that lets me start writing right away, but just after finishing, without having to press "tab" or anything else, just to press "Enter" to activate a button.

You don't need to have focus in two places to do that. You simply need to add a binding in your entry widget to invoke the button when the user presses the return key.

```
self.ctext1 = ttk.Entry(self.raiz, width=30)
self.boton1 = ttk.Button(self.raiz, text="Accept", command=self.raiz.destroy)
self.ctext1.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.boton1.invoke())
```